# Foreign Key with NO primary key to refer

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, oracle11g

I have following two tables.

```
CREATE TABLE parent
( c1 INTEGER );

CREATE TABLE child
(
 c1 INTEGER,
 c2 INTEGER,
 c3 INTEGER,
 CONSTRAINT fk_c3 FOREIGN KEY(c3) REFERENCES parent(c1)
);
```

You must have noticed that column `c1` is NOT a primary key in Parent table. 
Is there any way to refer it in Child table without making `c1` as a primary key?

Answer (score 6):

> Is there any way to refer it in Child table without making 'c1' as a primary key?

Yes. A foreign key needs only to refer to a *unique constraint* - it does not have to be a primary key. You could create a unique contraint on that column.

Comment: A foreign key needs a unique *constraint*, not a unique *index* :) [of course a unique index implies unicity, whereas a unique constraint can be policed by a regular index]